# Roblox script to enter dialog chat

Tags: input, lua, dialog, roblox

I need a script so that when you press E on the keyboard it will open up the chat with an npc I already have the dialog inside the head that I want to use. I also already have the code for detecting when you press E.

```
game:GetService("UserInputService").InputEnded:Connect(function(input,event)
    if input.KeyCode == Enum.KeyCode.E then
        print("Activated")
        workspace.NPC.Head.Dialog.InUse = true --This is the code I expect to open up the dialog.
    end
end)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```lua
game:GetService("UserInputService").InputEnded:Connect(function(input,event)
    if input.KeyCode == Enum.KeyCode.E then
        print("Activated")
        workspace.NPC.Head.Dialog.SomeGui.Visible= true -- example
    end
end)
```

Comment: This won't work because I only want it for the local player nothing to do with the server, but thanks for taking the effort to help

Comment: @CrannMoroney I'm not 100% certain but it's not possible to activate Dialog from any script. Alternatively, you could create a billboardgui instead of Dialog system.

Comment: I was half thinking this was the problem because I couldn't see any clear property for the Dialog that would Enable/Disable